# Share question, answer or comment on Android app

Tags: support, android-app, sharing

Is there any sharing functionality built into the Stack Exchange android app? This is something I use often.

Comment: I would hope they would just hook into the regular Android share mechanism.

Comment: You can share a question by tapping on the timestamp of the question. It does use the native Android sharing system.

Comment: Most recent excellent. I missed that.

Comment: I can't seem to edit my comment. Damn autocorrect!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Steven says in a comment, you can share by tapping on the "Asked xx mins ago" timestamp and selecting "share". This opens the standard android share activity.

Comment: Ugh. Not very discoverable. Do you have to deviate from the Android convention that much?

Comment: I agree it's not that easy to find. It is at least consistent in the app (I think) in that actionable elements have the little triangle. The share answer option should really be in the menu too I think though.

Comment: *Share question option I mean.

Comment: Going to mark this as an answer for now, this works for me.

Comment: For up voting comments, the triangle might work, but I was expecting to see a nice share icon next to or underneath the question title.